# Preferred way of collecting variables from a formula

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm dealing with propositional logic at the moment and I wrote two algorithms for collecting all variables in a formula. I want the output to be immutable. Which one should be preferred in terms of speed/elegance? Is there an even better way? Thanks in advance.

```
def getVariables(formula: Formula): Set[Variable] = formula match {
 case v: Variable => HashSet(v)
 case Negation(f) => getVariables(f)
 case BinaryConnective(f0, f1) => getVariables(f0) ++ getVariables(f1)
 case _ => HashSet.empty[Variable]
}

def getVariables2(formula: Formula): Set[Variable] = {
 def getVariables2(formula: Formula, set: mutable.HashSet[Variable]): Unit = formula match {
   case v: Variable => set += v
   case Negation(f) => getVariables2(f, set)
   case BinaryConnective(f0, f1) => getVariables2(f0, set); getVariables2(f1, set)
   case _ =>
 }
 val set = mutable.HashSet.empty[Variable]
 getVariables2(formula, set)
 set.toSet
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is almost always to use a builder.  So, assuming no stack overflows:

```
def getVars(formula: Formula): Set[Variable] = {
  val sb = Set.newBuilder[Variable]
  def inner(formula: Formula) { formula match {
    case v: Variable => sb += v
    case Negation(f) => inner(f)
    case BinaryConnective(f0, f1) => inner(f0); inner(f1)
    case _ =>
  }}
  inner(formula)
  sb.result
}
```

Your first version is probably the most elegant, however.

Note that if you may have very large formulas, this recursive solution could be in danger of stack overflows.  The fix is relatively straightforward:

```
def getVars2(formula: Formula): Set[Variable] = {
  val sb = Set.newBuilder[Variable]
  def inner(formulas: List[Formula]) { 
    var more: List[Formula] = Nil
    formulas.foreach{ _ match {
      case v: Variable => sb += v
      case Negation(f) => more = f :: more
      case BinaryConnective(f0, f1) => more = f1 :: f0 :: more
      case _ =>
    }}
    if (!more.isEmpty) inner(more)
  }
  inner(formula :: Nil)
  sb.result
}
```

Your names are way too long to allow convenient typing of an interestingly non-tiny expression, but if we abbreviate to the capital letters, then:

```
BC(N(V('x)), BC(BC(V('a),V('x)),V('y)))
```

will run about 7x faster with `getVars` than your first solution; `getVars2` is a little slower (only 4x faster).

(Benchmark timings are:

```
getVariables   1380 ns  +-  20 ns
getVars         190 ns  +-  10 ns
getVars2        360 ns  +-  10 ns
```

)